# Reference a .NETStandard 2.0 project from UWP project

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, .net-standard

I am building a Xamarin application, and I have implemented the core (using Xamarin.Forms) in a .NETStandard 2.0 class library. It is correctly referenced by an iOs and Android project which implements the platform-specific code.

The problem is, I tried to add an UWP project in order that my app supports UWP, and when I try to reference the core project, I have the following error:

> Project [Core project] is not compatible with uap10.0.10586 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10586) / win10-x86-aot. Project [Core project] supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using VS 2017 15.4(+)? : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/25/uwp-net-standard-2-0-preview/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to set both the *Target* and the *Minimum* version to *Windows 10 Fall Creator Update Build 16299* for your project.