# Xamarin forms: Issue reported while submitting windows app to windows store

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, windows-store

I have developed a **Xamarin Forms(.Net standard) UWP app** and submitted it to windows store, but the windows store team reject the app because of the following issue.

> The app doesn’t install on one or more of the currently selected device families due to an unsupported minimum OS version. If the affected device family is not intended to be targeted, then please de-select the unsupported device family and resubmit the app. Otherwise, please change the minimum and/or target OS version that the app supports (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/updates-and-versions/choose-a-uwp-version#choose-which-version-to-use-for-your-app)

My apps **min** and **target** versions are **Windows 10 Fall Creators Update(10.0; Build 16299)**. I am targetting my app only for windows 10 desktop devices and windows 10 mobile devices. **So what is the correct min and target versions for my app?**

**To Martin Zikmund:**

If I downgrade target version to 15063 (Creators Update) my windows app build failed with the following error.

[image]

The solution for this error is changed the target version to Windows 10 Fall Creators Update(10.0; Build 16299), I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47446699/reference-a-netstandard-2-0-project-from-uwp-project). If I changed the min and target version to Windows 10 Fall Creators Update the build will succeed.

Comment: So you have minimum and target version correctly set up?

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro I set Windows 10 Fall Creators Update(10.0; Build 16299) as the minimum and target versions, is that work for windows 10 desktop and windows 10 mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably trying to traget **Windows 10 Mobile**, which **did not receive 16299** (Fall Creators Update) and got stuck on a sub-FCU build. To support it, you would have to **downgrade to 15063** (Creators Update), but that means you can no longer use the latest versions of Xamarin.Forms which are targeting **.NET Standard 2.0 which is not supported on 15063** and have to downgrade to version 2.X of Xamarin.Forms. You will also have to downgrade your library from .NET Standard 2.0 to Portable Class Library.

Practically this means that to be able to use the latest and greatest of Xamarin.Forms you will likely have to drop support for Mobile and target the other SKUs only. Judging by the numbers it is probably a good idea nowadays, as most users are on Windows 10 Desktop, iOS and Android anyway.

Comment: If I upgraded the target version my build is failing, I updated the question with it's screenshots, can you please look.

Comment: My version of NETStandard.Library is 2.0.3

Comment: No, your original setup was correct. As I mentioned - if you downgrade, Xamarin.Forms will stop working as they use .NET Standard. You need to either uncheck Windows 10 Mobile from Dev Center when submitting the package, or you have to downgrade Xamarin.Forms to version 2.X and also downgrade your library from .NET Standard to Portable Class Library.

Comment: Can you please include this comment in the answer. I can't downgrade my app to PCL, because I have picture upload functionality in my project and `var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(picturepath);` works only in .Net standard. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54200559/xamarin-forms-how-to-convert-a-picture-path-to-mediafile

Comment: So I have only one option uncheck windows 10 mobile from dev center, right?

Comment: I have included it in my answer as well. If you need a functionality which is missing in PCL and you can't replicate it using platform specific code, then unchecking Windows Mobile is the only option. It is unfortunate, but bear in mind that the system is no longer supported and the userbase is really small now.

Comment: My windows app get approved by windows store when submitting the app with unchecking the windows mobile.

Comment: Glad to hear that :-) . Wish you great luck with your app!